# Time Complexity of algorithm to find the number of cycles of length n in an undirected graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, time-complexity, depth-first-search

I am currently learning code and I am struggling to figure out the time complexity of the following algorithm that I found online. Any help would be much appreciated.

I know that a normal DFS would have time complexity of O(V+E) but this algorithm only checks 3 paths for a node before checking if it completes a cycle.

```
# Python Program to count cycles of length n in a given graph. 

# Number of vertices 
V = 5

def DFS(graph, marked, n, vert, start, count): 

    # mark the vertex vert as visited 
    marked[vert] = True

    # if the path of length (n-1) is found 
    if n == 0: 

        # mark vert as un-visited to make 
        # it usable again. 
        marked[vert] = False

        # Check if vertex vert can end with 
        # vertex start 
        if graph[vert][start] == 1: 
            count = count + 1
            return count 
        else: 
            return count 

    # For searching every possible path of 
    # length (n-1) 
    for i in range(V): 
        if marked[i] == False and graph[vert][i] == 1: 

            # DFS for searching path by decreasing 
            # length by 1 
            count = DFS(graph, marked, n-1, i, start, count) 

    # marking vert as unvisited to make it 
    # usable again. 
    marked[vert] = False
    return count 

# Counts cycles of length N in an undirected and connected graph. 
def countCycles( graph, n): 

    # all vertex are marked un-visited initially. 
    marked = [False] * V 

    # Searching for cycle by using v-n+1 vertices 
    count = 0
    for i in range(V-(n-1)): 
        count = DFS(graph, marked, n-1, i, i, count) 

        # ith vertex is marked as visited and 
        # will not be visited again. 
        marked[i] = True

    return int(count/2) 

# main : 
graph = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
        [1 ,0 ,1 ,0, 1], 
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]] 

n = 4
print("Total cycles of length ",n," are ",countCycles(graph, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the normal DFS a vertice is marked as black after visited and stay black until the search's end. This garantee that a vertice will not be visited more than one time, making it possible to reach the O(V+E) complexity.

But in this DFS remove the vertice mark after visiting it. This causes the DFS to brute force every possible path available, so the number of times a single vertice can be visited grows exponentially.

For example, if you try this algorithm with `V = 20`, `graph = [[1]*V]*V`(fully connected) and `n = 8`, it will take a long time.

I don't recommend this algorithm if you are starting to study complexity, since brute force algorithms can be tricky. But answering the question, I think its about `O(V² * V!/(V - n)!)`.